# Facebook Like Button action not showing over activity Box

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am using facebook social like plugin which is not generating an activity post on my Activity box on facebook timeline, when I use this use the like button over this site

http://www.espncricinfo.com/england/content/image/646433.html?object=1;page=1

it generate the activity post on activity box as the normal like button do.

[image]

Someone please tell me what I am missing in it.

Here is the button code

```
<fb:like class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo SITE_URL.'/post/page/'.$post->id ?>" width="45" height="20" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="45" data-show-faces="false" fb-xfbml-state="rendered"></fb:like>



window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : social_ids.fb, // App ID
        status     : false, // check login status
        cookie     : true, 
        xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
        oauth      : true,  //enable oauth 2.0
        channelUrl: SITE_URL+'channel.php' //custom channel
    });                 
};
```

the wall post through this app is working fine, but normal like action is not reflecting over timeline.

Thanks

Comment: the like count is increment on like button but don't reflect over timeline. I've also added og meta tags